# Error when compiling

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

  int c, nl;

  nl = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) ! = EOF){
    if (c =='\n'){
      nl++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", nl);
  }

}
```

When I tried to compile using `gcc -o fun2 countline.c` 
I get this error

```
countline.c: In function 'main':
countline.c:12:26: error: expected ')' before '!' token
```

What is causing this error? What am I missing? I can't figure it out.

Comment: You probably want the `printf` outside the loop too :)

Comment: It implies your laziness in typing.

Answer (score 7):

The inequality operator is `!=`, not `! =`. That space makes the compiler interpret `!` and `=` as two separate operators (logical negation and assignment), which don't make sense in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Simple spacing issue, you need `!=` not `! =` so please fix that.

Your code becomes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c, nl;
  nl = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c =='\n')
      nl++;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
  }
}
```

I've cleaned the spacing a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

You've written `! =`. That should be `!=`. You just cannot put a space between the characters of an operator!

Answer (score 0):

Not: `(c = getchar()) ! = EOF`, use `(c = getchar()) != EOF`. The `!=` is a single operator!